# Azure Functions Kudu Logs: Retention, size and cost?

Tags: azure-functions, kudu

I just made an azure function.

So far everything works as expected and I can see the logs in the kudu console, download them on my local machine and analyze them with various tools.

Since I am trying to keep the budget as low as possible, I will not enable application insights at this time (maybe in future).

My questions about these kudu logs are:

- Retention: how long will these logs last?
- Size: How big they can grow?
- Cost: Are kudu logs free or there is an additional cost?

Comment: It is not free, and the charging standard refers to the charging standard of File Share. (Azure Function's logging is based on this.) If you don't generate a large number of log files, this part of the charge will be very small. You can use the cost calculator I mentioned in my answer to calculate the cost.:)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function App logging depends on Azure Storage Account. Your logs are basically stored in the File Share of the Storage Account, so the charging is based on this. If you do not use Application Insights, Azure will not charge you for log analysis fees.

Because you have not enabled Application Insight. Therefore, in the end, your cost is only two parts: the cost of Azure Function execution and the cost of files stored in the Storage Account.

> How long will these logs last?

Until you delete them.

> How big they can grow?

It depends on how much capacity your storage account can hold.

> Are kudu logs free or there is an additional cost?

It's not free, it's extra billing, kudu logging depends on Storage Account. If you do not generate a lot of logs, the cost of this part is very small. (You can refer to File Share charges)

You can use the cost calculator to estimate the cost:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/

Comment: Found the logs in the File shares but discovered old logs are automatically deleted ☹(I ignore by which criteria) so I enabled this setting https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings  destination=storage retention=0 days (forever). I see no new items in the storage but I hope the existing logs in file shares now will persist. Doc is confusing ☹ 
Also, Azure storage explorer GUI is a PITA, each time to see my logs I need to manually navigate to LogFiles/Application/Functions/Function/HttpStart,no way to set a shortcut 
There is room for improvement

Comment: @AntonM Can you briefly describe the problem you are experiencing? In addition, if you want to use kudu to view, it is necessary to enter the specified path.

Comment: @AntonM You said the old log was deleted? Did you perform any additional operations?

Comment: The problem is log files are auto deleted (I did no additional operation, it was automatic) and I want them to persist until I decide to delete. I have enabled the new log settings as described above and I will see next days if they persist. I have no problem viewing logs with Kudu and Azure storage explorer. I'd like in azexplorer shortcut to point directly to my logs but it's not possible. It's very annoying to navigate manually all the subfolders each time. These are feedbacks to improve dev experience.